# what is happening in the given numpy code. I'm confused for the last line print() statement

Tags: python, numpy-ndarray, numpy-slicing, numpy-indexing

## the print() statement will print the rows of array X??

```
import numpy as np
X = np.arange(12).reshape((3, 4))
row = np.array([0, 1, 2])
mask = np.array([1, 0, 1, 0], dtype=bool)
print(X[row[:, np.newaxis], mask])
```

```
X = [[0, 1, 2, 3],
     [4, 5, 6, 7],
     [8, 9, 10, 11]]

row = [0, 1, 2]
mask = [True, False, True, False]
```

array row changes to a 2d array after adding a new axis. shape of row is (3,1)

```
row = [[0],
       [1],
       [2]]
```

after print(), the result
HOW??

```
  [[0, 2],
   [4, 6],
   [8, 10]]
```

Answer (score 0):

To understand the given Python code and the output it generates, let's break down the process step by step, focusing on the key components involved: NumPy arrays, indexing, and the manipulation of shapes for advanced selection.

**1. NumPy Array Creation**

The code starts by creating a 2D NumPy array named X:

`X = np.arange(12).reshape((3, 4))`

- np.arange(12) generates a 1D array with numbers from 0 to 11.
- .reshape((3, 4)) reshapes this array into a 2D array with 3 rows and 4 columns:

`[[ 0,  1,  2,  3], [ 4,  5,  6,  7], [ 8,  9, 10, 11]]`

**2. Index Arrays**

Two additional arrays are defined:

- row = np.array([0, 1, 2]) specifies row indices.
- mask = np.array([1, 0, 1, 0], dtype=bool) is a boolean mask for selecting columns.

Since True corresponds to 1 and False to 0, it effectively becomes [True, False, True, False], meaning that it will select the first and third columns and skip the second and fourth.

**3. Adding a New Axis**

- row[:, np.newaxis] transforms row from a 1D array ([0, 1, 2]) into a 2D array by adding a new axis:

`[[0], [1], [2]]`

This change in shape is crucial for the next step.

**4. Advanced Indexing**

The expression X[row[:, np.newaxis], mask] performs advanced indexing on X:

- row[:, np.newaxis] indicates which rows to select, and its 2D shape allows for broadcasting.
- mask selects columns based on its boolean values.

Because row has been reshaped to a 2D array, and mask is a 1D boolean array, NumPy broadcasts them to perform element-wise selection. This means for each row specified by row, it selects elements where mask is True.

**5. Result Explanation**

The final output is:

`[[ 0,  2], [ 4,  6], [ 8, 10]]`

Here's how the result is achieved:

- For the first row [0, 1, 2, 3], applying the mask [True, False, True, False] results in [0, 2].
- For the second row [4, 5, 6, 7], the same mask yields [4, 6].
- For the third row [8, 9, 10, 11], again, the mask results in [8, 10].

Thus, the operation selects elements [0, 2] from the first row, [4, 6] from the second row, and [8, 10] from the third row, aligning with the specified row indices and column mask. This demonstrates a powerful aspect of NumPy's advanced indexing capabilities, enabling complex selections through broadcasting and boolean masking.

Comment: understood, i was just little confused thanks @alex